# Same Referer URL opens for two different browser tabs with different URLs PHP

Tags: php, url, http-referer

Flow:

```
- user visits a page say www.mysite.com/somepage/1
- user clicks on Log Out button or times out and logs out
   *user log out detected redirect to home page but save the referer URL
   *redirect to /login?ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (actual code test if its set)
- user sees login page and relogs back
- user is redirected back to refere url that is saved in $_GET['ref']
```

the aboe flow works perfect for **first browser tab**, if user has multiple tabs open then `$_GET['ref']` gets set to same URL that is set for first tab. For example:

**EXAMPLE:**

```
  Tab 1 : /somepage/hello/world
  Tab 2: /another/page/1
```

when user logs out from **Tab 1** gets redirected to:

`/login?ref=http://site.com/somepage/hello/world (CORRECT)`

If user refreshes the page on **Tab 2** gets redirected to:

```
/login?ref=http://site.com/somepage/hello/world 
   NOT CORRECT, IT SHOULD REDIRECT TO: 
/login?ref=http://site.com/another/page/1
```

Comment: not really possible. you can't reliably detect if/when a user has multiple windows/tabs open on your site, or which particular window an event came from.

Comment: It looks like you're just re-directing only to obtain the HTTP_REFERER later. That is pretty indirect. Just store the actual URL *before* redirecting and add it as a parameter in the redirect instead so you already have it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't redirect anywhere. Handle the re-login process on the same URL the user is already on. This will keep the URL of every tab and browser window intact.

Comment: You can even redirect, however that redirect should already preserve the URL in form of a parameter. This is effectively the same as what you suggest in your answer, just with a redirect ;)

Comment: Right. The trick is not to preserve the original URL in the session, but in the URL. I wouldn't recommend too much redirecting nonetheless.

Comment: if it was up to me thats exactly what i would do, but i need a way around it to do it with redirects.

Comment: Sure if you can prevent redirecting all-together this has the benefit that on pages you keep open in other tabs while you log off and then log-in back again might even look more transparent to the user (albeit  re-login should regeenrate the session id so I'd say there is at least one redirect necessary but only for the ID update and the redirect is to the same URL anyway, not a login / home page).

Comment: @GGio: Don't save in session. Don't use HTTP_REFERER. Save in URL parameters *before* the redirect, do the redirect with that URL parameter.